# How to get the checked radio button on a custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, radio-button

How could I possibly get the radiobutton that was checked in a custom dialog.
I have a custom dialog with 2 radiobuttons in it but everytime I clicked the radiobutton, a null pointer exception occurs.

Comment: Hi. It will be helpful if you'll post your code. :)

Answer (score 1):

While initialising the radio button use `RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);` instead of `RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);`

Comment: i already know the answer before you post :) i did the same way. thanks :)

Comment: It doesn't mean that you know the answer or not he posted a correct one, you must have to give him correct answer tag.